# Mongoose distinct values with sort

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I am trying to implement `distinct()` with `sort()` but it isn't working, The documentation also says it isn't supported, so I tried using `aggregate()` to find the values.

With `distinct()` i am trying like

```
HISTORY.distinct("source", { "sourcedBy": "Nithin" }, function (error, source) {
   console.log(source);
});
```

I am getting output but I want the results to be based on descending `_id` and limited to the last 3 distinct values.

So using `aggregate()` I wrote a query like this

```
HISTORY.aggregate([
{ "$match": { "sourcedBy": "Nithin" } },
        { "$group": { _id: { source: "$source" } } },
        { "$project": { _id: 0, source: "$_id.source" } },
        { "$limit": 3 },
        { "$sort": { _id: -1 } }
    ]).exec((err, source) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(source);
    });
```

But it is giving an empty array.

Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: You don't have `createdAt` field in the model? And also you have vanished your `_id` in `{ "$project": { _id: 0, source: "$_id.source" } },` stage. And also `$limit` stage should be come after the `$sort` stage.

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet `createdAt` field is there, oh okay i'll fix limit and _id one.

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet, i'm still getting am empty array.

Comment: Could you show some sample collections?

Comment: If you haven't already done it: An easy way to debug an aggregation is removing all but one pipeline-step and adding them back one by one, always checking where the logic fails.

Comment: @BenSower, Thanks. Will do that from my next aggregation queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below aggregation

```
const source = (await HISTORY.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "sourcedBy": "Nithin" } },
  { "$group": { "_id": "$source", "createdAt": { "$max": "$createdAt" }}},
  { "$sort": { "createdAt": -1 }},
  { "$limit": 3 }
])).map(({ _id }) => _id)

console.log(source)
```